# asp.net ssrs - table misplaced in relation to page header

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I have an ssrs report in Visual Studio 2012. When viewed in browser report control, Google Chrome specifically, page one is perfect. Pages beyond one show the table moved way to the right, in relation to page header, which is placed correctly in the report control.

I tried making the report narrower, because it is in landscape mode and occupied almost all the space in the page bounds, but it keeps showing this way. I must repeat: page one shows perfect; pages beyond one (2, 3, 4, ...) show this incorrect way.

I must add: when converting to pdf, everything shows perfect; so the incorrect placing of the table occurs only in Chrome report control.

I'm attaching an image of page two just for the issue to show for itself.

Many thanks for your help and bye ...

[image: Note table is moved to the right, regarding page header ...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your body size (width, actually) to "lock" the table in place, preventing it from moving right. I usually use 10 inches because I can print landscape with 0.5 inch margins on each side.

Comment: Hi sfors, maybe I'm missing something here, but the reports keeps showing the table moved to the right. I reduced the report width to 9 1/2 inches and used 0.5 inches for each side margin. So, as the landscape for letter is 11 inches, it should still have .5 inches left. Any suggestion would be very appreciated. Thanks ...

Comment: Make sure your table is 9.5 inches too so it has nowhere to move.

Comment: Hi sfors, sorry for the late comment. I did what you suggest, but take off a very tiny space from the table at every side (left, write). So, if available space in the report is 9.5'', the table is 9.4'' (or maybe 9.3''). I centered the table horizontally in the report, so it has a very tiny margin on each side. Every thing is working fine now. The table does not move to the right, even when you go to a diferente page in the report control in the browser. So many thanks for all the help; it is very much appreciated. Bye ...